# Show Current Time in Excel by Timezone

Tags: excel, excel-formula, timezone, formula, formulas

I have searched all over and any answer or code I find is rather confusing.

I am looking to convert the =NOW function in excel to a different timezone(s)

I am currently using

```
=TEXT(NOW(), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

which displays my timezone EST

I would like to convert this to another time zone

for example PST.

is there a way to do

`=TEXT IF C1 equals PST subtract 3 from A1 <--- the current time`

what im trying to do is if one column has the letters PST in it I want to convert the =NOW by subtracting 3 hours from my EST Time Zone.

sorry if my question is a little confusing.

I know im not the only one searching this so an answer would help me and future users, thanks so much in advance.

UPDATE:

so I was able to use

```
 =TEXT(NOW()-0.125, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

to subtract 3 hours, but not make an if statement for 2 or more timezones

Comment: Time zones are MUCH more complicated than just subtracting three hours.  You have DST transitions to contend with, and if you want to support time zones from around the world then you'll not be able to rely on abbreviations.  To get a real solution, you'll likely need to program a VBA script or possibly write an Excel plugin.  Are you prepared to do that? An excel-formula solution is also possible, but require importing multiple sheets of time zone rules and complex parsing formulas...  If you can narrow your requirements you can probably find an acceptable compromise that is less involved.

Comment: ...Note to self:  Write an Excel plugin for time zones. ;)

Comment: Your timezone in June is much more likely PDT (Pacific Daylight Time, UTC–7h), not PST (Pacific Standard Time, UTC–8h). No US state officially observes Standard Time in summer, sadly.

Answer (score 4):

Try this `formula` in `B3` cell for individual

```
=TEXT(NOW()-TIME(hour,minute,second),"hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

and by using `IF` statement for 2 or more timezones in `B6` cell

```
 =IF(B1="GST",TEXT($A$1-TIME(1,30,0),"hh:mm:ss AM/PM"),
  IF(B1="BST",TEXT($A$1-TIME(4,30,0),"hh:mm:ss AM/PM"),
  IF(B1="EST",TEXT($A$1-TIME(9,30,0),"hh:mm:ss AM/PM"),
  IF(B1="PST",TEXT($A$1-TIME(12,30,0),"hh:mm:ss AM/PM"),
  IF(B1="AST",TEXT($A$1-TIME(6,30,0),"hh:mm:ss AM/PM"),
  IF(B1="ACST",TEXT($A$1-TIME(2,30,0),"hh:mm:ss AM/PM")))))))
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What about when day light savings occurs. You want to use the HOURS() function in Excel and subtract the necessary hours for each times zone. You'll also need to handle crossing midnight in your calculation. If you just want to play around with what you have started see the below link for something more accurate to your stated post.

Check this link [add and subtract time in excel](https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/how-to-add-or-subtract-time-in-excel/)

Try this:

=IF(B3="PST", =TEXT(NOW()-0.125, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM") ,=TEXT(NOW()))

Comment: thanks for the reply! I was able to manually do it by placing =TEXT(NOW()-0.125, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM") inside the time column. is there a way to add an IF statement so I dont have to manually do it?

Comment: Yes...=IF(cell='PST',True condition, False condition)

Comment: More accurately something like this....=IF(B3="PST", =TEXT(NOW()-0.125, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM") ,=TEXT(NOW()))

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment instead.